# python venv "activate.bat vs activate.ps1 vs deactivate.bat"

Tags: python-venv

I named my virtual environment `.venv`.
I went into `.venv/Scripts/` and there were `activate.bat` and `Activate.ps1`. My guess is that I need to run `activate.bat` or `Activate.ps1` to access the virtual environment, but I don't know the difference between `activate.bat` and `Activate.ps1`.

And I want more. what is difference between `activate.???`and `deactivate.bat`?
Also, why isn't `deactivate.ps1` there?

And I am using powershell.

Looking on the internet, it says to use `activate.bat`, but they seem to use cmd. I want powershell.

Answer (score 1):

`ps1` is for powershell and `bat` is for cmd.

Comment: Hey, thanks but what's deactivate.bat? and why there are no deactivate.ps1?

Answer (score 0):

No doubt we do not have deactivate.ps1 but we can deactivate the virtual environment by just typing 'deactivate'

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using powershell and your virtual environment name is `.venv`, then you should activate your virtual environment using this command

```
.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Then, to deactivate the environment, just enter

```
deactivate
```